# webpack only bundle firebase/database and not firebase/auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, webpack, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my react app. I only use the `firebase/app` and `firebase/database` modules, so I want webpack to bundle only what I used. However, webpack bundles everything in the firebase module. I cannot figure out how to tell webpack to ignore other modules.

I thought my issue was

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

However, I tried to import only bits and pieces of firebase.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import firebase from 'firebase/database';
```

but, webpack still bundles up `auth.js` and other unused modules.

[image: webpack bundle analyzer]

Here is my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
      main: "./src/swap.tsx",
      vendor: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'events',
        'fbemitter',
        'flux',
        'react',
        'react-dom'
      ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/app/assets/javascripts",
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
        ]
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `firebase/app` and `firebase/database` to your vendor bundle array